# sklearn coef_ lists in Ridge, RANSAC and linear regressions

Tags: python, scikit-learn, regression, pickle, coefficients

I'm attempting to understand a couple of pickle files, and trying to map the input variables to the corresponding coefficients.

One thing I noticed was the `coef_` list always has one more data point than the inputs list

```
linearvar = pickle.sensor[0].models['linear'].inputs
linearvardf = pd.DataFrame(data = linearvar, columns = ['linear_variables'])
linearvardf.shape
(857, 1)

linearcoef = pickle.sensor[0].models['linear'].pipeline._final_estimator.coef_
linearcoefdf = pd.DataFrame(data = linearcoef, columns = ['linearcoef'])
linearcoefdf.shape
(858, 1)
```

So I figured out the first row of `coef_`  - refers to the intercept value of my linear regression model.

However the same logic doesn't apply to other models e.g. Ridge and RANSAC regressions. The first row of coef_ in these models don't match with the intercept values. In all cases I have set `fit_intercept = True`. Any idea why this is the case?

Comment: I don't think it's the coefficient. If you use 'LinearRegression' from sklearn, the coefficients should be as long as your input, and the intercept is stored under .intercept_

Comment: Since it's part of a pipeline, i think the most likely scenario is that your pipeline is adding a column

Comment: @StupidWolf Thanks for your messages. yes they are all part of the pipeline and i think you are right thinking the pipeline is adding a column. in `pickle.sensor[0].models['linear'].pipeline.named_steps.polynomialfeatures` i can see `n_input_features_` = 857 and `n_output_features_` = 858.  At the top level of pickle file there is a `pickle.sensor[0].model_inputs_list` , consisting of all variables from all models I assumed. Is the additional column recorded somewhere in the file or is it something I can only identify by reading the scripts?